# What is the minimum jQuery version that supports the jQuery UI Range Slider?

Tags: jquery

I'm curious what the minimum required jQuery version is to use with the jQuery UI Range Slider plugin.

Testing it with 1.5.7 I get slider() is not a function, however with jQuery 1.7 it works fine.

In addition, are their any tweaks that I could make in order to make the slider work with an older version of jQuery?

Comment: I see the slider going back to 2009 on github, so my guess is that it might be because it uses new functions/naming introduced later on in jquery. So going backwards in jqery-ui might help you. Ill try to test it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure nothing else is wrong?

Created a test on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeaeY/

Seems to work fine with jQuery all the way back 1.3.2 (older and it fails)

(Testing with jquery-ui 1.8.18 - since you didn't write your version)

Comment: Hah, I knew it couldn't have been a jQuery version issue. Thanks for testing! It's likely a CMS issue then.  I'm using Drupal with a module that updates the internal jQuery version, so I think there's probably an issue with that.  Will tinker and figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Maybe you could try comparing the jquery file with the offical one, to see if the match. Else check the order of the scripts. Best of luck :)

Comment: I'm guessing it ended up being a theme issue. I switched out my theme and it worked fine. ;-)